# What's the approximate data scale that an ssh session will consume?(without file exchange)

Tags: ssh

When traveling during holidays, sometimes I need use my mobile as a WiFi hotspot to let my notebook connect to server to do some task.

Then a question comes to my mind: How much web data will be consumed by an ssh connection?

If I don't use scp or other stuffs to copy file between server and my notebook. Will it just costs me the data of stdout that will show on my terminal. Or there are some stealth bulk web data transfer beneath the ssh tunnel?

If my consumption is right, so an normal ssh will only costs at most several megabytes of web data transfer, was it true?

Comment: My limited experience is that ssh has little overhead, easily compensated for by using `-C` to compress the stream ( repeating parts in prompts etc). With that you will probably find there is less bytes transfefred than show up on your screen unless you do something really random.